# Why does an error 'TypeError: 'int' object is not callable' when trying to print the value of the max() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First version of the code:

```
a = []
n = int(input())
a.append(n)
while n != 0:
    n = int(input())

print(max(a))
```

Second version of the code:

```
a = []
n = int(input())
a.append(n)
while n != 0:
    n = int(input())

print(str(max(a)))
```

Why does the second one work, and the first doesn't?

Comment: I get no errors while running either version. Both generated the same output: the first number entered by the user. Please post the entire stacktrace in the question.

Comment: Your code is certainly not doing what you expect it to do (as is, it print the first value given and ignores all others. You may want to include ``a.append(n)`` in the ``while`` loop). But it does not raise a TypeError. Unless you type something that is not an int, but even then, it would not be about not being callable. Or at least I fail to see any situation where such an error would be raised,

Comment: @MichaelRuth what Python version do you have installed?

Comment: You probably did `input = something` earlier when you were working.

Comment: More importantly: which Python version do _you_ have installed? We want to reproduce your environment, not mine.